# Can't find httpd.pid to use for Monit apache2 monitoring

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, httpd, monit

I'm new to Linux and I setup Ubuntu 12.04 on Digital Ocean.

I installed Monit and got it to monitor MySQL successfully with email alert.

I want to monitor Apache2 as well but cannot find any `httpd.pid` file needed to put in monitrc file.

I can start Apache2 with: `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`

I can stop Apache2 with: `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

I can restart Spache2 with: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

What other way is there to monitor Apache2 in Monit without a httpd.pid file?

Answer (score 7):

If you look in the init script it uses the value of $APACHE_PID_FILE which it reads from the file defined as $APACHE_ENVVARS which I think defaults to /etc/apache2/envvars

```
PIDFILE=$(. $APACHE_ENVVARS && echo $APACHE_PID_FILE)
```

In the envvars file PIDFILE is defined as

APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX.pid

Unless you are running multiple instances of apache2 $SUFFIX will likely be "" so the value of $APACHE_PID_FILE will be

```
/var/run/apache2.pid
```

but you should be able to run

```
echo $(. /etc/apache2/envvars && echo $APACHE_PID_FILE)
```

and get what your system thinks the value is.

Comment: I found: /var/run/apache2.pid

Comment: @Bergen: there you go then - problem solved - ✔

Comment: In monitrc file i put: #apache2
check process apache2 with pidfile /var/run/apache2.pid
group apache
start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80
protocol http then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout

Answer (score 1):

On Centos, there is a good chance that you use "service" utility to manage deamons. Services are configured in directory: `/etc/init.d/`

In file `/etc/init.d/httpd`, you will find the pid file location. I see something `like pidfile=${PIDFILE-/var/run/httpd/${prog}.pid}`

So, it turns out that my pidfile is located at `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid`

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would try:

1. See if you can configure Apache to write out a PID file.  Ref:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#pidfile
2. Modify apache2 start/stop script to create a PID file during the start/stop using the `pgrep` command.  Ref:  http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples

Answer (score 0):

if you install Apache 2.4 or through chef cookbook(https://github.com/sous-chefs/apache2)
then the location would be /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid